# Drawing semi-ellipse(s) in a XY plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw something like in the picture below.

[image]

So far I have the following MWE. Any help is more than welcome.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.12,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
    %enlargelimits=false
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[samples=200,smooth,hide axis]
    \addplot[domain=0:360] {abs(sin(2*x))};
    \addplot[domain=2*360:3*360] {0.5*abs(sin(x))};
    \addplot[domain=4*360:5*360] {abs(sin(2*x))*(x<4.25*360)};
    \addplot[domain=4*360:5*360] {abs(sin(2*x))*(x>4.75*360)};
    \addplot[domain=4*360-360/8:4*360+360/2.65,red] {0.5*abs(sin(x-360/2.65))};
    \addplot[domain=5*360-360/8:5*360+360/2.65,red] {0.5*abs(sin(x-360/2.65))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are using `pgfplots` and not just TikZ?

Comment: No, nothing special. It can be TikZ. I used `pgfplots` because I though about the `sin` or `cos` function to draw the shape. However, as it can be seen, the result is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using TikZ:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip
  (0,4) rectangle (16,0);
\foreach \Value in {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,12,14}
  \draw[fill=red] (\Value,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5,y radius=2];
\foreach \Value in {7,9}
  \draw[fill=red] (\Value,0) ellipse [x radius=1,y radius=1.3];
\foreach \Value in {12,14}
  \draw[dotted] (\Value,0) ellipse [x radius=1,y radius=1.3];
\end{scope}

\draw[-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (16,0) node[below=2pt] {BB};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[left=2pt] {BB};

\foreach \Value in {1,...,15}
  \draw (\Value,-2pt) -- (\Value,2pt);
\foreach \Value in {3,8,12.5}
  \node[below] at (\Value,-2pt) {AA};

\draw[dashed] (1,2) -- (14,2);
\draw[dashed] (6,1.3) -- (10,1.3);
\draw[latex-latex]  (8,1.3) -- (8,2);
\draw[shorten >= 2pt] (7.5,2.5) node[above] {AA} |- (8,1.65);
\foreach \Value [count=\xi] in {5,10}
  \draw[-latex] ([xshift=10pt]\Value,1) -- coordinate (aux\xi) ++(0.8,0);
\foreach \Value in {1,2}
  \draw[shorten >= 2pt] (aux\Value|-7.5,2.5) node[above] {AA} -- (aux\Value);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a very good start. Thanks. However not all the ticks are correct, especially in the right part.

Comment: @cacamailg Please see my updated answer.

Comment: That gives me some room to do some adjustments for my original problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the `arc` command instead of clipping away ellipses,
something like

```
\draw (0,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180, x radius=0.5, y radius=2];
```

Comment: Would you show a complete solution instead of only a hint?

Comment: I've updated the answer to a more descriptive syntax. 
Sorry, I don't see a point in going through the whole example because the question is clearly about how to draw sections of an ellipse.
Remove the clipping from the OP, replace the ellipse command by arc and add the start/end-angles, and you've got your complete solution. Read section 14.7 ("The arc Operation") of the manual -- it explains everything better than I ever could.